# Linkedin ads "rest/adAnalytics" api data is missing when we increase time rage

Tags: linkedin-api

**API Details:**

https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics

**Req body** -
q=analytics&pivot=MEMBER_COMPANY&timeGranularity=DAILY&fields=actionClicks,pivotValue,comments,costInUsd,dateRange:(start,)commentLikes,adUnitClicks,companyPageClicks,conversionValueInLocalCurrency,costInLocalCurrency,externalWebsiteConversions,impressions,clicks,cardClicks,&accounts[0]=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:XXXXXXX&&**dateRange.start.day=6&dateRange.start.month=4&dateRange.start.year=2021&dateRange.end.day=6&dateRange.end.month=10&dateRange.end.year=2023**

**header**

X-HTTP-Method-Override = GET
Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization =
Connection = Keep-Alive
Linkedin-Version = 202301

when we set 2 year date range some company entrys are missing but we set 3 month date range all data comes perfectly.

We need to download all record by large date range.